# Display/hide an element depending on next element's class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, display, getelementsbyclassname

Here's a question that will probably seem easy to experienced javascript users but that I can't solve by myself.

I'd like to add a javascript code that displays or hide an element (h1) if the next html element has a specific class. No parent/child here, only next element.
Please note Jquery is already loaded.

Here's the example:

```
<h1>This must be displayed because next element is div class="show"</h1>
<div class="show">
  <p>Show header above</p>
</div>

<h1>This should not be displayed because next element is NOT div class="show"</h1>
<div class="dontshow">
  <p>Don't show header above</p>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.
regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.prev()` to get immediately preceding sibling and then show/hide them.

```js
$('div.show').prev('h1').addBack().show();
$('div.dontshow').prev('h1').addBack().hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>This must be displayed because next element is div class="show"</h1>
<div class="show">
  <p>Show header above</p>
</div>

<h1>This should not be displayed because next element is NOT div class="show"</h1>
<div class="dontshow">
  <p>Don't show header above</p>
</div>
```

Refences

- [`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)
- [`.addBack()`](https://api.jquery.com/addback/)

Comment: very short n sweet :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling) to get the previous sibling element.

```js
document.querySelector('.dontshow').previousElementSibling.style.display = 'none';

document.querySelector('.show').previousElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
```

```css
.dontshow {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>This must be displayed because next element is div class="show"</h1>
<div class="show">
  <p>Show header above</p>
</div>

<h1>This should not be displayed because next element is NOT div class="show"</h1>
<div class="dontshow">
  <p>Don't show header above</p>
</div>
```

For older browser check [polyfill option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling#Polyfill_for_Internet_Explorer_8).

Answer (score 1):

Please find below snippet

```js
$( "h1" ).each(function( index ) {
  if($(this).next().hasClass("show"))
  {
   $(this).show();
  }
  else
  {
   $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>This must be displayed because next element is div class="show"</h1>
<div class="show">
  <p>Show header above</p>
</div>

<h1>This should not be displayed because next element is NOT div class="show"</h1>
<div class="Hide">
  <p>Don't show header above</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as an aside, why not just put the h1 tags inside the div?:

```
<div class="show">
  <h1>This must be displayed</h1>
  <p>Show header above</p>
</div>

<div class="dontshow">
  <h1>Don't show</h1>
  <p>Don't show header above</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Because structure is generated by a CMS. ^^

Comment: The CMS will probably be generating content based on a template - it might be worth seeing if this can be edited rather than using JS (of course if you have access to it!).

Thanks, just checking anyway ^^